# What is the use of ** in C++?

Tags: c++

```
Segment computeSegment(Triangle& t, float z)
{
    Vertex** vs = t.vertices;
    // ...
}
```

Here, `Vertex` is the name of a structure.  Can you tell me what is the meaning of `**` in `Vertex** vs = t.vertices;`?

Comment: Learn the use of `*` and you will understand `**`.

Comment: Given the names of the variables, I assume that a `Triangle` has a member `vertices` that is a pointer to an array of pointers to `Vertex`es so `vs[0]` would give you a *pointer* to the first vertex.

Comment: Without `**` we could not have `***`, and then we could not have a [three star programmer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer)

Answer (score 2):

`Vertex*` is pointer-to-Vertex, so `Vertex**` is pointer-to-pointer-to-Vertex -- one more level of indirection.

For example:

```
int i = 0;
int * iPtr = &i;        // iPtr -> i
int ** iPtrPtr = &iPtr; // iPtrPtr -> iPtr -> i
```